# Design principle underlying std::condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, c++11, condition-variable

The C++ [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) is similar to Windows' [Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396(VS.85).aspx). While the latter is designed to be used alone, `std::condition_variable` must be used with `std::mutex`. I know about many use cases where a `std::condition_variable` and `std::mutex` combination would be perfect. I also know that in certain cases, something that can be used alone like Windows' Event would come in handy. So, I begin to wondering the design underlying `std::condition_variable`. Is it because `std::condition_variable` and `std::mutex` are often used together, or `std::condition_variable` itself uses the `std::mutex` to implement its functionality?

Comment: There is a good [article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29#Condition_variables) that explains such design and contains links to research papers. It is also shown there how different synchronization primitives can be implemented in terms of each other, so it may be completely possible to have a different 'basis'. As for c++, it's condition_variable design came from widely used posix threads, so it was not created out of nowhere.